# Passing Excel string array to user defined VBA function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I wish to use an Excel array function to generate an array of strings and then pass this to a user defined function to strip blanks and concatenate the strings separated by a `","`.

I have a function that does this when called from a VBA macro.  When I try to use it as a user defined function, e.g. `=ConcStr({"A","B","C"})`, I get a `#Value!` error.

Function is below:

```
Sub StrTest()
    Dim StaticArray(1 To 3) As String
    Dim Result As String
    StaticArray(1) = "A"
    StaticArray(2) = "B"
    StaticArray(3) = "C"
    Result = ConcStr(Arr:=StaticArray)
    MsgBox Result
End Sub

Function ConcStr(Arr() As String) As String
    MsgBox "started"
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Total As String
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        MsgBox Arr(N)
        Total = Total & "," & Arr(N)
    Next N
    ConcStr = Total
End Function
```

Comment: IIRC, you cannot interchange fixed size arrays and dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your UDF to accept a `Variant` instead, it should work. Also, you can just use the `Join` function to accomplish what you need:

```
Function ConcStr(arr As Variant) As String
    ConcStr = Join(arr, ",")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what you want with:

```
Public Function ConcatString(ByVal arr As Variant) As String
    ConcatString = vbNullString
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, z as Long
    z = LBound(arr) : n = UBound(arr)
    For i = z To n
        ConcatString = ConcatString + arr(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

[image: use]

Comment: A UDF with array argument `{"A","B","C"}` does not pass as an static array in VBA. Variant is what should be used instead.

Comment: What if the `arr` being passed in was zero-based, e.g. with an LBound(arr) of 0? Your For... Next is going to skip the first array element.

Comment: Well yes. So I fixed the post. I was assuming it was going to be used as an UDF only.

Answer (score 0):

Declare, dim, assign and pass the array over as a variant.

```
Sub StrTest()
    Dim StaticArray As Variant, Result As String

    ReDim StaticArray(1 To 3)

    StaticArray(1) = "A"
    StaticArray(2) = "B"
    StaticArray(3) = "C"

    Result = ConcStr(Arr:=StaticArray)
    MsgBox Result
    Result = ConcStr2(Arr:=StaticArray)
    MsgBox Result

End Sub

Function ConcStr(Arr As Variant) As String
    MsgBox "started"

    Dim N As Long, Total As String

    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        MsgBox Arr(N)
        Total = Total & "," & Arr(N)
    Next N

    ConcStr = Mid(Total, 2) 'Mid to get rid of the first comma

End Function

Function ConcStr2(Arr As Variant) As String
    'could just be like this,
    ConcStr2 = Join(Arr, ",")
End Function
```

I've added an alternative [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) version to simplfy things and modified your function with the [Mid function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to remove the leading comma.

Comment: Thank you all, much appreciated